# How to convert the parameters of an HTML webform to use with TIdHTTP in Delphi?

Tags: php, delphi, upload, transfer, idhttp

How to convert the parameters of an HTML webform to use with TIdHTTP in Delphi?

I have a web server, with PHP, and a function to upload files. Via a web browser, I can send files without problems, but when I use TIdHTTP, it presents an error.

This is the HTML for the file upload page:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload de Arquivos com PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
     
<form method="post" action="recebe_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Arquivo:</label>
<input type="file" name="arquivo" />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
     
</body>
</html>
```

This is the procedure I used to send the files:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Response, URL : String;
  LHTTPClient : TIdHTTP;
  Lista : TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
  server, script, caminhoarq : string;
begin
  URL := 'http://192.168.15.101/RECEBE_UPLOAD.php\';
  Lista := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
  HTTPClient.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
  HTTPClient.Request.ContentType := 'utf-8';
  HTTPClient.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible;Indy Library)';
  HTTPClient.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams, hoKeepOrigProtocol];
  Response := '';
  try
    try
      Lista.AddFormField('Arquivo','C:\Client\teste.txt');
      Response := UTF8Decode(Trim(HTTPClient.Post(URL, Lista)));
      memo1.Lines.add(response);
    except
        on e : exception do
          ShowMessage('Erro ao enviar arquivo ao servidor! Detalhes: '+e.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Lista.Free;
    HTTPClient.free;
  end;
end;
```

This is the error message I get:

```html
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: arquivo in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\RECEBE_UPLOAD.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: arquivo in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\RECEBE_UPLOAD.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\RECEBE_UPLOAD.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not populating the `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` correctly. You need to use the `AddFile()` method, not the `AddFormField()` method. The latter is meant for text fields instead.

Also, PHP's `$_POST` is case-sensitive when accessing webform fields. The HTML sends a field named `arquivo`, but your Delphi code is sending a field named `Arquivo` instead.  That is why the PHP error says `arquivo` is unknown.

Also, the URL you are posting to is wrong, and the `ContentType` you are setting is wrong (though `Post()` will overwrite it).

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Response, URL : String;
  LHTTPClient : TIdHTTP;
  Lista : TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  URL := 'http://192.168.15.101/recebe_upload.php';
  Lista := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    Lista.AddFile('arquivo', 'C:\Client\teste.txt');

    HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      HTTPClient.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
      HTTPClient.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams, hoKeepOrigProtocol];
      try
        Response := Trim(HTTPClient.Post(URL, Lista));
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Response);
      except
        on e : Exception do
          ShowMessage('Erro ao enviar arquivo ao servidor! Detalhes: ' + e.Message);
      end;
    finally
      HTTPClient.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Lista.Free;
  end;
end;
```